# CSS Animation Timing Function with steps() to try to blink colors, but colors are blending

Tags: css, css-transitions

I've been trying to blink two colors, using the following CSS rules but the colors just ends up blending.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1kyba3rd/

Here are the CSS rules:

```
<style>
    .block {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid black;

        /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -webkit-animation-name: flash-colors; 
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(2, start);
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        /* Standard Syntax */
        animation-name: flash-colors;
        animation-duration: 1s;
        animation-timing-function: steps(2, start);
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    @-webkit-keyframes flash-colors {
        0% {
            background-color: white;
        }
        100% {
            background-color: yellow;
        }
    }
    /* Standard syntax */
    @keyframes flash-colors {
        0% {
            background-color: white;
        }
        100% {
            background-color: yellow;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: do you need this - http://jsfiddle.net/1kyba3rd/1/

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the blinking is not working properly because you have set `background-color:yellow` at the end of the animation (100%) and the `background-color:white` at the beginning, set first one at `50%` so that the animation works as expected - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1kyba3rd/2/)

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you so much!